# toArray(new MyObject[size]) vs iterating over list and filling the array

Tags: java

which one of the following methodologies is safe from performance hits, assume that the size of List is large (may be 1,000 objects).

**i)**

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();

for(int i=0; i <=10; i++){
    myList.add(""+i);
}

String[] array = myList.toArray(new String[myList.size()]);

myArrayMethod(array); // this method returns the array - it modifies the content but not size of array.

myListMethod(myList); // this method processes the list.
```

**ii)**

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();

for(int i=0; i <=10; i++){
    myList.add(""+i);
}

String[] array = new String[myList.size()];
int i = 0;
for(String str : myList){
   array[i] = myList.get(i);
   i++;
}
myArrayMethod(array); // this method returns the array - it modifies the content but not size of array.

myListMethod(myList); // this method processes the list.
```

Comment: 1000 items is large? Oh.

Comment: replace foreach by normal for in ii) example

Comment: @dantuch I don't know why there is foreach, str variable is unused. i++ is near end for-body. In this case better is normal for

Answer (score 3):

The first example is slightly more efficient as it can use System.arraycopy() internally.

However, compared to everything else you are doing e.g. creating the Strings, it makes a very little difference and I would suggest you do what you believe is clearer

Answer (score 3):

toArray() is much readable and faster.

If you look at source code toArray method you'll notice that there are some conditionals and arraycopy method.

```
// ArrayList.class:
public <T> T[] toArray(T[] a) {
    if (a.length < size) 
        return (T[]) Arrays.copyOf(elementData, size, a.getClass());
    System.arraycopy(elementData, 0, a, 0, size);
    if (a.length > size)
        a[size] = null;
    return a;
}

// System.class
public static native void arraycopy // native method
```

The arraycopy is much faster for huge array than manually adding. I've tested it, I checked duration for i) and for ii)

- i) your first example: toArray
- ii) your second: manual adding

100 000 elements:
i) 2 ms
ii) 12 ms

1 000 000 elements:
i) 10 ms
ii) 65 ms

Answer (score 2):

I would go with option 1 if it were my code, because I just have a feeling the Collections API will do this better than I will.

Answer (score 1):

Relatively speaking they have the same performance characteristics, so given that, use the built in version

```
String[] array = myList.toArray(new String[myList.size()]);
```